# Usage of Merge Statement in case of multiple IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Stored Procedure which uses multiple `IF NOT EXISTS` conditions

```
Create procedure AuditLogProcDetails
(@Id                 int,
 @LogId          int,
 @LogDescription varchar(2000),
 @LogStartDate   datetime     ,
 @LogEndDate     datetime     ,
 @Task               varchar(100)   
)
as 
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.AuditLogging where LogId = @LogId and Task = @Task )
    begin
      INSERT INTO dbo.AuditLogging( Id, LogId, Task, LogDescription, StartTime       , EndTime)
                             VALUES (@Id,@LogId,@Task,@LogDescription,@LogStartDate, @LogStartDate)
    end
  ELSE
    begin
      UPDATE dbo.AuditLogging
         SET LogDescription = @LogDescription,
             StartTime = @LogStartDate,
             EndTime=    @LogEndDate 
       WHERE ProcessId = @LogId
         AND Task      = @Task

    end
  -- COMMIT;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.AuditLogging where LogId = @LogId and Task = 'INPROGRESS' )
        DECLARE @SetStartTimeInProgress datetime;
        DECLARE @TotalCount int;
    begin

        SET @SetStartTimeInProgress = GETDATE();
      UPDATE dbo.AuditLogging
         SET StartTime = @LogStartDate,
             EndTime=    @LogEndDate 
       WHERE LogId = @LogId
         AND Task      = 'INPROGRESS'        
    end

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.AuditLogging where LogId = @LogId and Task = 'COMPLETED' )
        DECLARE @SetStartTimeCompleted datetime;
        DECLARE @TotalCount int;
    begin

        SET @SetStartTimeCompleted = LastRunStartDate FROM LogTable  WHERE LogId=@LogId and Status='COMPLETED';
      UPDATE dbo.AuditLogging
         SET StartTime = @SetStartTimeCompleted,
             TOtalCount=    @TotalCount 
       WHERE LogId = @LogId
         AND Task      = 'COMPLETED'         
    end

END
```

How can I refactor above Stored Proc Code and use more effective `MERGE` statement in place of `IF NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: `MERGE` is not 'more effective'. It's just a different set of code. Out of those three statements it's probably only worth replacing the first insert/update with a `merge`. The other two you can probably remove the `IF EXISTS` altogether since if the records don't exist, the `update` won't do anything anyway.

Comment: I think you can declare some variables. For example, declare inprogress int and then  set inprogress = SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.AuditLogging where LogId = @LogId and Task = 'INPROGRESS' . Finally, check inprogress > 0. Just suggest, my friend!

Comment: Is it possible to use Merge and CASE together in UPDATE query ?

Comment: for second and third `if` statements have the `begin` statement in the wrong place. since they are not followed directly with the `begin` statement they only control the first row after them. [Check this demo to see what I mean.](http://rextester.com/FPKXR7623)

Comment: Hi Zohar Peled , Thanks , can I just remove those begin statements in second and third If ? will it be ok ?

Comment: I think you can remove the second and third if statements and just leave the updates. I will try tp make an example when I'm on a computer.

Comment: Thanks Zohar Peled , if possibe please show an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AuditLogProcDetails
(
    @Id             int,
    @LogId          int,
    @LogDescription varchar(2000),
    @LogStartDate   datetime,
    @LogEndDate     datetime,
    @Task           varchar(100)   
)
AS
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS 
  (
      SELECT * 
      FROM dbo.AuditLogging 
      WHERE LogId = @LogId 
      AND Task = @Task 
  )
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO dbo.AuditLogging(Id, LogId, Task, LogDescription, StartTime, EndTime)
      VALUES (@Id, @LogId, @Task, @LogDescription, @LogStartDate, @LogStartDate)
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
      UPDATE dbo.AuditLogging
      SET    LogDescription = @LogDescription,
             StartTime = @LogStartDate,
             EndTime=    @LogEndDate 
      WHERE  ProcessId = @LogId
      AND    Task      = @Task

  END

  DECLARE @SetStartTimeInProgress datetime;
  DECLARE @TotalCount int;

  SET @SetStartTimeInProgress = GETDATE();

  UPDATE dbo.AuditLogging
  SET StartTime = @LogStartDate,
      EndTime   = @LogEndDate 
  WHERE LogId   = @LogId
  AND Task = 'INPROGRESS'        

  SELECT @SetStartTimeCompleted = LastRunStartDate 
  FROM LogTable  
  WHERE LogId = @LogId 
  AND [Status]  = 'COMPLETED';

  UPDATE dbo.AuditLogging
  SET StartTime  = @SetStartTimeCompleted,
      TOtalCount = @TotalCount 
  WHERE LogId = @LogId
  AND Task    = 'COMPLETED'            
END
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)